# react dropdown option elimination

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'm new to ReactJS but I'm trying to create four drop down menus that all have the same options to select, but when an option is selected I need that option to be removed from all the other drop downs.

Comment: Can you please provide some code explaining what you've already tried?

Comment: @Mooneruma Please tell us what you have already tried and what was the result. Provide some code of what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need a parent component that should store all used values and pass them as a property back to dropdown components, so they know which options should be eliminated

```js
const options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
const isNotUsed = unavailable => item => unavailable.indexOf(item) === -1;

const Select = ({ onChange, unavailable, value, field }) => (
  <select onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)} value={value}>
    <option key="">Choose</option>
    {options.filter(isNotUsed(unavailable)).map(item => (
        <option key={item} value={item}>{item}</option>
    ))}
  </select>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      values: {}
    };
  }

  handleChange(field, value) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      values: {
        ...state.values,
        [field]: value,
      }
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const unavailableFor = (field) =>
      Object.keys(this.state.values)
        .map(key =>
          key !== field
            ? this.state.values[key]
            : null
        )
        .filter(Boolean); // remove empty

    return (
        <div>
          {['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'].map(field => (
            <Select
              key={field}
              field={field}
              unavailable={unavailableFor(field)}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, field)} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Try it](https://jsfiddle.net/jprogd/69z2wepo/91041/)

Comment: Ok Ill look using a parent list that will effect the children as well. Also that code didn't work for me or is it incomplete.

Comment: What kind of error do you have? Did you tried this link: https://jsfiddle.net/jprogd/69z2wepo/91041/ ? The result should appear on the bottom right corner.

Comment: Never mind your a pro and a gentleman works great. It just didn't load up for some reason at first.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Mooneruma do you need any assistance with the code?